# Error 0xc0202009 while importing a text file to SQL Server using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to import a text file of 200k rows into sql server using sql server management studio 17. but its showing the following error:

```
Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification.".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc020901c: Data Flow Task 1: There was an error with Destination - DimStudent.Inputs[Destination Input].Columns[DateOfBirth] on Destination - DimStudent.Inputs[Destination Input]. The column status returned was: "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type.".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)


Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Destination - DimStudent.Inputs[Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907A occurred, and the error row disposition on "Destination - DimStudent.Inputs[Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Destination - DimStudent" (158) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Destination Input" (171). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc02020c4: Data Flow Task 1: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Source - DimStudent_txt returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

I'm new to this. it would be great if someone could tell how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error message states:

```
"Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type.".
```

One of the rows has a value that does not fit into the destination table for some reason. You didn't specify the datatypes, but I am guessing the output column might not be a proper date/time column.

However, without knowing the table setup and/or seeing some of the data, we can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into same error, I had columns that were set not to allow null by the auto import. Set them to allow nulls and everything completed.